# An Interface Add method, how to add default implement for all class

Tags: eclipse

Now I have a interface DetailUI, and I have thousands of class implements the DetailUI interface, and I want to add a method isXXX(), and I want all the current class automatically implements the method and the method return true by default, is there a simple way in eclipse ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there's another way, but you can

- add the method declaration in the interface
- go to the *Problems* view, select one of the compilation errors caused by the new method, right-click and choose *Quick Fix*
- Choose "Add unimplemented methods", and select all the other classes in the bottom of the dialog

This will make the generated methods return false, though:

```
public boolean isXXX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

So you could search and replace with the following regexp for search:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub\R\s*return false;
```

And the following replacement string:

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Go to the "Problems" view, and select all of the problems indicating that you're missing the method ("The type XYZ must implement the inherited...").
After selecting them all, right click and choose "Quick Fix".

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions may not be ideal in the case of a class hierarchy that implements the interface -- if there's an abstract super class, it won't flag an error due to another missing method. I found it more convenient to view use the Type Hierarchy view (F4 on Windows) to find the top level classes and add the method there.

Another alternative is to upgraded to Java 1.8 which allows default implementations. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html